# How to make my wireless internet or WiFi device secure for personal use?

Tags: wifi, internet

Sometimes I have seen that my internet packets are being consumed after all I did not use it but my device is connected and ready for use. So it is due to some other reasons or someone is using my internet packets. I want some suggestions to make my internet connection more secure.

Comment: You mean, consuming your bandwidth? One does not consume packets.

Comment: Is your wifi protected with a password? If so, are you using WPA2 or WEP? If you are using WEP, don't, use WPA2 instead. If that doesn't help check the logs of the router to see what other devices are connecting and block them?

Comment: Your devices send and receive packets even if you're not using them. They check for updates, check for new notifications, synchronize time and date, download new emails, etc. Even your router alone uses some bandwidth to check for updates and sync clock.

Answer (score 2):

Well, WiFi internet security is one of the major issues that the users are always complaining so I am going to share some quick tips to make your internet connection secure.

In the first step you need to open your router setting page you can only do that by typing “192.168.1.1” in your browser page and then enter your user name and password which can be given in the user manual of the internet router, usually each routers have different access.

Step 2. Create a Strong Password:
After logged in to your account all you need is to change your default password and to make it secure. Generally to change your password there are default values admin and password. Once you have done this your device will be automatically disconnect from the other devices.

Step 3. Change your SSID name of Network
Generally SSID name of the connection is defined as “default” or at the name of your internet brand for e.g “cyberetnet”. The change in the user name does not make your internet connection more secure but it can create difficulty for the others to know about the network they are connecting too.

Step 4. Enabled your network encryption:
Well, this option will prevent the other computer in your area to use your internet connection. All you need is to enable the encryption of your network.
In order to enable this feature you have to login to your wireless router security setting configuration page and choose its security method. For the older devices WEP is more reliable and for the other devices you choose WPA2.  To make a strong passphrase use small, capital, numeric and special characters to make it difficult for the other users.

Step 5. To Filter the MAC devices:
Every laptop, cellphone and other WiFi enabled devices have its own IP addresses and to prevent other users to use your device you can put the IP of only those devices which you wants to connect and others can’t connect to your device.
Almost every MAC address is hardcoded in network equipment, so one address will only allow one device to connect. If the attacker want to attack for spoofing first they have to find the MAC address of the device in which the network in connected and it very difficult for them to find.

Step 6. Upgrade your Router’s firmware, time to time: For this purpose you should have to check the manufacturer site time to time for the latest updates of your firmware. To find your existing firmware version you can check the router’s dashboard at 192.168.*.

All the above steps mentioned are enough to make your [internet connection](https://timewarnercablebundledeals.com/Internet.aspx) completely secure and safe from attackers.

Comment: I will change the password and username to check the consumption of my bandwidth. I think it will work.

Comment: I don't think that `192.168.1.1` is always the router's admin page. It varies by model and configuration.

Comment: I'll add that the SSID name is used as [salt in WPA2](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/49653/10885). As such, having a unique one is critical to prevent precomputation attacks